# Is there a way using geopandas/shapely/fiona to get highest point withing a polygon?

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, fiona

I have points shapefile and polygons shapefile. I would like to find out the highest point within each polygon.
I have done an intersection to find out which points belong to each polygon:

```
import geopandas as gpd

from geopandas.tools import sjoin

point = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(pointSHP)
print("POINT", point)
poly = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(polygonSHP)
print("POLY", poly)
points_within_poly = gpd.sjoin(point, poly, how="inner", op='intersects')
print(points_within_poly.head(10))
```

Now I would like to select the highest point for each index_right. I think is a matter of sorting by Z value in geometry column but I am having problems to do it. I don't know how to extract the Z coordinate from geometry using geopandas. Finally I would like to do a spatial join and populate the Z value to the nearest point (another shapefile).

Thank you

Comment: To get the value of `z` from 3D point in your case, just use `point.geometry[0].z` for the first item in the geo-dataframe.

Comment: thank you swatchai, do you know how can I keep the point with the highest value for each polygon? After that, I just need to join that point with another set of points within the same polygon by using the polygon ID. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll focus on the first question, use this to extract the `z` coordinate

```
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = gpd.read_file("file.shp")
gdf['z'] = None
gdf['z'] = gdf.geometry.apply(lambda x: list(x.coords)[0][2])
```

or alternatively,

```
z_values = [list(x.coords)[0][2] for x in gdf.geometry]
gdf['z'] = None
gdf['z'] = z_values
```

explanation: for each geometry, make a list of the `coords` from the geometry, take the first`[0]`  of the `coords` list, and take the third `[2]` value which is the z value of the geometry (because the first `[0]` is the x, and the second `[1]` is the y value).
the spatial join part from nearest neighbor is too long to be written. I suggest asking a new question for this topic.